# How to change /etc/my.cnf in cPanel account

Tags: cpanel

I have create an account and I want to modify /etc/my.cnf but it says it is read-only, what should I do?

Comment: Do you have root access console?

Answer (score 0):

To change the mysql configuration you should be logged in as root

if not check if you have sudo privileges to modify the mysql configuration file

If you still has issues with it you need to check if the file has the attribute set on it using the below command

```
lsattr  /etc/my.cnf
```

if its shows you the attributes applied to it remove it using below command

```
chattr -aiu  /etc/my.cnf
```