# How to find my.cnf file through cpanel?

Tags: cpanel

I want to edit 'my.cnf' file on server.But it not found under 'etc' folder.  where can I find it in cpanel - files?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's configuration file is editable only by root. You can see it only through SSH

You can refer to other posts, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509406/how-to-change-etc-my-cnf-in-cpanel-account)